# Memory usage when loading the same script in an iframe and parent window

Tags: html, iframe

I was wondering if I load JQuery, for example, in an iframe as well as in its parent window.  Does it use memory for both the iframe and the parent?  Does it create two instances in memory?

Answer (score 1):

In short yes, however, if both the parent and the iFrame download it from the same URL, the browser should cache it, so you'll only download it once.

Comment: In terms of memory usage by the browser, if the parent and iframe make a JQuery call do each of them now call a seperate instance of JQuery?

Comment: yep, although given the size of the average web page in relation to jQuery I doubt it's worth worrying about. Chrome often uses around 100MB per page and jQuery is 60k.

Comment: Definitely, I used jQuery as an example.  Problem is with code I inherited.  It loads a route of the same web app into an iframe.  So was wondering what the impact of this would be, which displays it in a small section on the screen.

In my opinion writing a proper view would be a better option.

Comment: yuk and yes rewriting is the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does create two instances in memory. For example, if you load jQuery and jQuery UI in an `<iframe>`, and just jQuery in parent document, the jQuery instance in parent document doesn't get any of the jQuery UI features.

And if you think about it, it makes perfect sense because consider a scenario where you load a different application in an `<iframe>`, if both the parent and `<iframe>` share same instance of jquery, the `<iframe>` can do evil things like modifying jQuery methods hence crashing the parent.